# Tutorial for using sirius Modeling with Xtext

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext, xtend, sirius

I have created an xtext project from the tutorial given by their main site, but I want to integrate Sirius with the xtext project so that I can edit a diagram or the dsl file itself with each edit reflecting on the other editor view also with code generation, I have found a white paper saying that this can be done somehow, but I am looking for a step by step guide to tell me how to make the project.
the link:
https://www.obeodesigner.com/resource/white-paper/WhitePaper_XtextSirius_EN.pdf

I expect that I can have xtext dsl editor and a diagram editor in the eclipse runtime for the same file.